# What is the rationale for making calculateWinner() a helper function and not a component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am following the official React tutorial, which describes a helper function that checks for a winning combination for a Noughts & Crossesgame (Tic-tac-toe).

It does this by checking for the presence of a winning combination in a components state, and either returns the winning X/O or null object:

```
//Board component
return{
    const winner = calculateWinner(this.state.squares);
}

//helper function
function calculateWinner(squares) {
  const lines = [
    [0, 1, 2],
    [3, 4, 5],
    [6, 7, 8],
    [0, 3, 6],
    [1, 4, 7],
    [2, 5, 8],
    [0, 4, 8],
    [2, 4, 6],
  ];
  for (let i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    const [a, b, c] = lines[i];
    if (squares[a] && squares[a] === squares[b] && squares[a] === squares[c]) {
      return squares[a];
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html#declaring-a-winner

My question: what is the rational be for making calculateWinner() a helper function and not a method on the Board component or a functional component?

Is it due to the separation on concerns i.e. the function does not directly affect the UI?

Comment: imo. it's a private implementation detail. It might change in the future, or even get completely obsolete. You don't want to expose this function to other parts of your code, they might start using it ;) And then you have to be careful when changing this implementation and that all it's behaviours *(including/especially potential quirks)* stay the same, or some dependant code may break.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it due to the separation on concerns?

Yes. It makes no sense to have that function as a method on Board, as it is not accessing the board in any way.